# Page cannot be displayed CHM / Compiled HTML Help Files

Tags: windows, chm

I've started getting "Page Not Found" errors for no apparent reason when trying to view compiled html help files, for some reason (image below).

[image: CHM Viewer]

I've seen [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/50443/chm-compiled-help-files-all-give-not-found-error), of which none of the answers have helped me.

I'm on Windows 7 64bit. Any suggestions as to what the problem might be? And if not, are there other/better viewers/readers for .chm files I could try?

Edit: Forgot to mention the file and path names don't contain any invalid characters. I have the same problem with every and any .chm file I try to open.

Comment: Does the path contain a space or a # at all?

Comment: @RandolphWest - Nope, nothing like that it's definitely a valid path and filename.